# How to get list of perl subroutines with start and end line number of subroutine?

Tags: regex, perl, unix

I am writing a script for build and upgrades analysis where i need to fecth all subroutines defined in perl module with their start and end line number.

What is best way to achieve this?

Comment: can the PPI module be useful?

Comment: Is there a rule against posting the same question elsewhere?

Comment: @rfportilla not sure if it's a rule, it makes sense not to waste the time of people if it's already answered somewhere else

Comment: No, no rule - it's just a matter of politeness if it's answered in one place, to reference the answer.

Comment: @rfportilla: It's considered polite to say so if you've posted the question elsewhere so that people's time isn't wasted. Having said that, I don't think I've ever seen a question that says, “and, by the way, I also asked this question on Perl Monks”.

Comment: Part of the reason I ask is b/c I noticed that a few people have voted down this question.  I think its a good question and am wondering why it's being voted down.  At the time the only comment was that it was posted elsewhere.  I think if the question can be improved, a suggestion should be made in addition to voting down.  jmho

Comment: yup, i only posted it on perlmonks and reason is pretty clear, more the inputs, more solid output. for one of my question related to perl i didn't get answer on stack. then same question I posted to perlmonk and i get answer. This time i followed same pattern.

Comment: guys, sorry if anything went wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not trivial to learn how to use [`PPI`](https://metacpan.org/pod/PPI), but once you do, it is trivial to use `PPI` to solve this problem.

```
use PPI;
$FILE = ...;
$doc = PPI::Document->new($FILE);
$subs = $doc->find('PPI::Statement::Sub');

foreach my $sub (@$subs) {
    my @t = $sub->tokens;
    #my $name = $t[2];  # usually good enough to get the sub name
    my $name = $sub->name;
    my $start = $t[0]->location->[0];
    my $end = $t[-1]->location->[0];
    print "$name => $FILE: $start - $end\n";
}
```

Comment: cannot you just use $sub->name to get the sub name?

Comment: Yes, yes you can. Edited.

Comment: just faced issue with PPI. one of my subroutine have this line at end of sub - 

"return ($ni_lookup->{$verifier_model}, $ni_lookup->{elements});"

PPI is braking here, and showing sub list till this sub only. All other subsequent subroutines are getting ignored. 

But when i am removing last parameter from this return statement like "return ($ni_lookup->{$verifier_model}" , it is working properly.

Answer (score -1):

Hah!  This sounds like an interesting problem.

I've never done this before, but from writing some csv functions, I know it can be deceptively complicated.  This would be my approach.  You need to have a parser.  In the parser you will have to know what the beginning of a sub looks like (basically `/\s*sub\s+.*\{/` or something similar).  You are then looking for the closing '}'.  You will then have to loop through every character looking for string and block markers like `[\(\)\{\}'"]` (I tried to include backtick, also, but it is reserved for the web page).  These should be stored in an array.  so that you can keep track of how nested you are and identify when you have a the correct closing bracket.  While you loop through lines, you can keep track of the line that you are on.

I hope this helps.

Comment: infact i have more interresting problem i am working on :) , part of that i wated to get this chunk solved.

Comment: Awesome.  I hope you find this useful.

Comment: actually i did something like `cat UpgradeUtils.pm | grep -En '^sub '` this given me start line.

Comment: I guess you assume that sub will always be at the beginning of the line (i.e. no white space in front).  Still, you will need a parser to go through line by line to do this.  Actually, a perl script is probably the easiest way.

Comment: Perl supports recursive regex patterns. They can be used for that. However, for a stable solution I would use  a [perl parser](http://search.cpan.org/~zefram/Parse-Perl-0.007/lib/Parse/Perl.pm)